# How to set SharePoint list view 'Item Limit' with the option "Display items in batches of the specified size." programmatically

Tags: list, development, office-365, item, settings

How to set SharePoint List View **'Item Limit'** programmatically with the option ***'Display items in batches of the specified size.'*** selected.

By default, *'Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount.'* option is selected. I want to change it to *'Display items in batches of the specified size.'*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below mentioned code

```
    using System.Net;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

    namespace ClientObjectModelConsoleApplication
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://hercules");
          clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "12345");
          string listName = "My Custom List", viewName = "All Items";



          // true is "Display items in batches of the specified size"
          // false is "Limit the total number of items returned to the specified amount"
          bool paged = true;      



          List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
          View view = list.Views.GetByTitle(viewName);
          view.Paged = paged;
          view.Update();
          clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: "view.Paged = true;" is working,..Thanks..